# Method swizzling in an ObjC SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, method-swizzling, objc-category

I am working on writing a new `HTTP Library` sort of SDK. For implementing cross cutting concerns we are planning to write middleware support similar to c# i.e. mechanism to handle retries, redirection, logging etc.

Will it be a good idea to use method swizzling to swizzle some of the `NSURLSession` methods to achieve above mentioned objective?